# Does the Live Agent API really use Long Polling?

Tags: liveagent

I see in this documentation:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_http_long_polling_loop.htm that the Live Agent API uses long polling, but from the way it seems to behave in my REST client, I think the API just uses polling.  Why does it seem this way to me?

For example, in my REST client, calling the /Messages resource will immediately return with a 200 code and a list of messages that the agent has sent already.  If long polling were really in use as I understand it, then I think I would see a delayed response, which would come only when I send a chat in the Live Agent widget.  So it seems that I should repeatedly call the /Messages resource, say at an interval of a few seconds, in order to get messages as the Live Agent widget sends them.

Just to disclose, I've never used either polling or long polling, or at least I can't remember using them.  I'm a little familiar with webhooks though!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it really is a long-polling loop. As the documentation says, if there are messages, you get them instantly. If there are no messages, the connection remains open until the client times out or new messages are received. This means that you don't need to "poll every few seconds." As soon as you get new messages, your code will automatically receive those messages. You don't need to manually poll every few seconds to get new messages.

Comment: Sfdcfox... This means that you don't need to "poll every few seconds." As soon as you get messages, you can check for new messages... In this statement what is meant by "as soon as you get messages" where we will receive this one and where to check for this

Comment: @Bujji This is kind of poorly worded. I'll amend this answer.

Comment: thanks for update.. If we go further in my case customer will be using Facebook chat and from there the message will come to my middle ware system, this middle ware system will establishes the salesforce live agent chat using the rest api. When agent sends messages it will be delivered to middle ware and then passes to customer face book chat. If we go with this long pooling my middle ware has called session id api--->chatiatorapi-->chatmessage to pass customer message to agent and finally system/messages api to know the new messages. In this case how does my middle ware get notifies

Comment: @Bujji Your middleware does the same thing as what would happen on the client; the Messages call will wait until there are new messages. The call does not immediately return unless there are new messages to process.

Comment: do {
  // await means we're waiting for a response back
  let response = await callMessagesApi();
  /* When we get here, we have a response. This might be seconds 
   * or even minutes after the previous line of code started
   * executing.
   */
  if(response.status != 200 && response.status != 204) {
    break; // We didn't get a valid response
  }
  // Do stuff with the new messages here
} while(true); // Loop forever here,  i think this has provided some better understanding thanks sfdcfox such a quick draft

Comment: thank you so much for detailing it helped me a lot to understand the missing peace. One last question as per my understanding after all this discussion "for every chat request we need to call System/messages api only once" that would continue till the session is ended

Comment: @Bujji Correct. Correct.

Comment: thank you so much for help and time. Will try out this and update you in case of any concerns.. Thank you once again